# How to let ONLY my browsers access the internet? -without installing a firewall (WinXP)

Tags: windows-xp, internet

So that background applications like Adobe Update don't eat away my internet.
One way is to install a firewall and configure it but is there any other way? Like with registry keys? Can Windows' default firewall help me in this?

Comment: If you're running Windows XP, why not just use Windows Firewall to block everything EXCLUDING the programs you define?

Comment: How? Where is the option?

Comment: It appears that Windows XP has a restricted featureset for Windows Firewall. After further research, it is apparently impossible to do what you require on Windows XP without third party software. See here for more info: http://superuser.com/questions/344423/how-do-i-block-all-outgoing-ports-in-windows-xp-firewall