# Windows Firewall: Block everything except one app on port 80

Tags: windows, windows-firewall

I'd like to block all outgoing port 80 activity except for one particular application.

Why? I want to test a piece of software to see if it will fall back to a proxy if a direct connection to the web is not available. I need to allow my proxy to connect, but nothing else.

I would have thought this would be a comon scenario, but I'm not able to find anything that gives a hint as to how to accomplish this.

BTW, this is on Windows 7

Comment: OK, figured it out. You need to open the Windows Firewall properties, and set Outbound connections to block (it's set to Allow by default). Then, you add an Allow rule for your proxy app.

It did what I wanted for testing purposes, but obviously not something to change long term.

Answer (score 8):

You can accomplish this by using the Advanced Security settings panel.

Open up the Windows Firewall Control Panel item and click "Advanced settings":

[image: Control Panel]

(You can also open Advanced Security by opening the Start Menu and typing "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security".)

Click on Windows Firewall Properties:

[image: Windows Firewall with Advanced Security]

Select "Block" from the "Outbound Connections" menu:

[image: Properties box]

Click OK, then create a new outbound rule. Click on Outbound Rules (in the left sidebar), and then click on "New Rule":

[image: outbound rules]

Comment: Similar to http://superuser.com/a/268909/109468

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and hope freeFirewall application solve it.
My connection's bandwith is too low so when I play online games I needed to block all other applications. But this app has Gaming mode which I hope to do the job.

[image]

Install it from [their website](https://www.evorim.com/en/free-firewal)