# Allow trusted IP and Block others in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, ip, firewall, windows-server-2008

For protection of a Web Server, I need to allow some trusted IP and block others.
The solution I have tried:

1. Create 2 inbound rules :

   - Allow some IP and RDP IP
   - Block All

   this resulted on blocking every connection. I learned that Windows Firewall block everything explicitly ignoring the allowed rules.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755191%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

2. This is not true
   https://serverfault.com/questions/51146/windows-firewall-2008-server-allow-only-given-ip-in-block-all-others

> By default, anything that does not have a rule is automatically
>   blocked by the built-in firewall in Windows server 2008. So to make
>   this work, all I needed to do was add a rule specifically allowing the
>   IP address to get in.

Although the firewall is turned on and creating inbound rules that allows trusted IPs , random IP can still access the Server either with RDP or HTTP request.

3. I tried this
   [How to block all traffic but one IP in Windows Firewall?](https://superuser.com/questions/268902/how-to-block-all-traffic-but-one-ip-in-windows-firewall)

Create outbound rule: Block All 
Create Inbound rule : Allow some IP 
It does not have any effect. The connection are open despite the firewall is turned on with these rules.

Windows Firewall Properties - screenshot
http://postimg.org/image/stg1jtxjh/

please help!

Comment: What do you mean with "access the server"? Are you trying to limit RDP connections? There are a lot of rules which allow incoming traffic for all kinds of services.

Comment: hi @duenni i am not only trying to limit RDP connection but also http request to server. do you understand?

Comment: Option 3 **does** work however you must also check every other rule. If you already have a rule that allows RDP from any IP then that rule will allow access even if your IP block does not. **If traffic matches any rule at all it will be allowed**

Comment: @qasdfdsaq hi. There is no special rule created other than the trusted IP rule. It is a success also on testing a http request from random IP to the server IP which should be prohibited.

Comment: This is why I said you have to check **every other rule**. Including the 20+ Windows built-in ones

Comment: @qasdfdsaq hi . I am testing on the local network. the block outbound rule did deny connection.
http://postimg.org/image/hthhauayr/

but eventhough outbound rule has been created, allowed trusted PC ,as below image , the connection is still blocked. please help me!
http://postimg.org/image/85jtsnaxb/