# How to block all traffic except one in windows

Tags: windows, networking, firewall

I am trying to block all outbound traffic except one.

I have referred to this post but it does not seem to help much

[How to block all traffic but one IP in Windows Firewall?](https://superuser.com/questions/268902/how-to-block-all-traffic-but-one-ip-in-windows-firewall)

What i am trying to achieve is this.

Any outgoing connection can happen but the destination must be of 
x.x.x.x:8083

The IP and port number must be the destination of the packet for all packets leaving the firewall else it will be denied

Comment: Which part of the answer that you linked to was not working?  Basically you set the default to Block All - then you add the single exception.

Comment: @albal i cannot find the place to add the exception

Comment: Using the first picture as a reference from http://superuser.com/questions/268902/how-to-block-all-traffic-but-one-ip-in-windows-firewall - Right click on `Outbound Rules`, then `New Rule...` - an `exception` is a `rule`