# Which IP should I allow in Firewall for AnyDesk?

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall

At my computer I block in Windows Firewall all IP addresses (as described by the link https://superuser.com/a/268909) except those I added as allowed to a Firewall rule.

The page https://support.anydesk.com/Firewall says that only IP **239.255.102.18** should be allowed for AnyDesk. But when I add it to my Firewall rule, I still see the orange warning that AnyDesk can't connect to its network and my AnyDesk address is 0.

Which IP address(es) should I add to my rule to enable AnyDesk?

ps. Win 7 Home Premium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: to create a Firewall rule to allow AnyDesk as a program and thus to allow all the IPs the program needs